# ADFS can be implemented in Mono for Android

Tags: android, active-directory, xamarin.android, adfs, ws-trust

I'm making an application that must be connected to an ADFS. I wonder if it is possible in MonoDroid. Investigating I found a code for Windows Phone but MonoDroid no such classes. The code is

```
        var client = new WSTrustClient(new WSTrustBindingUsernameMixed(),new EndpointAddress("https://adfsserver.domain.com/adfs/services/trust/13/usernamemixed"),
                       new UsernameCredentials("DOMAIN\\user", "user password"));

        client.IssueCompleted += new EventHandler<IssueCompletedEventArgs>(client_IssueCompleted);
        var rst = new RequestSecurityToken(WSTrust13Constants.KeyTypes.Symmetric)
        {   
            AppliesTo = new EndpointAddress("https://yourRelayParty.domain.com/")
        };

        client.IssueAsync(rst);
```